# Prove that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3}$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3}$ is irrational ?

These are my steps -

$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3} = a$

$3 = (a-\sqrt{2})^{3}$

$3 = a^{3} -3a^{2}\sqrt{2} + 6a -2\sqrt{2}$

$3a^{2}\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2} = a^{3}+6a-3$

$\sqrt{2}(3a^{2}+2) = a^{3}+6a-3$

Then, $\sqrt{2}$ in the left side is irrational , and mulitply irratinal with rational is irrational.
The right side is rational.
So,  $irrational \neq rational$.

This is a good proof ?

Comment: Seems good to me.

Comment: Why is the RHS rational?

Comment: You're mostly correct. You have the right idea, but you wrote an incorrect thing and another which is misleading. "Multiply irrational with rational is irrational" is incorrect (why?). It's easier to just observe that $\sqrt{2}$ equals a rational number, a contradiction.Then you write that as a conclusion irrational numbers are different from rational numbers.This is always true, it doesn't just follow from what you wrote. At best you would want to say something like "and because no rational number can equal an irrational number, the proof is done".

Comment: Furthermore, at the start you should have explained what you're doing. Something like "Suppose $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3}$ is rational. Then there exists $a$ in $\mathbb Q$ such that $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{3}=a$".

Comment: @GitGud I was wondering why they assumed $a^{3}+6a-3$ is rational, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Alomst a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1571593/1508), posted yesterday. Your solution is the same as [the answer from André Nicolas](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1571612/1508).

Comment: Is this a proof by contradiciton? Are you assuming $a$ is rational and then argue that that assumption leads to a contradiction?

Comment: Another minor note on your proof: The statement "irrational times rational is irrational" only holds if the rational factor is $\neq 0$. In your case, this can easily be verified.

Answer (score 1):

Taking powers of $\alpha=\sqrt2+\sqrt[\large3]{3}$ and putting them into matrix form, we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^0\\\alpha^1\\\alpha^2\\\alpha^3\\\alpha^4\\\alpha^5\\\alpha^6
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&0\\
2&0&0&2&1&0\\
3&2&6&0&0&3\\
4&12&3&8&12&0\\
60&4&20&15&3&20\\
17&120&90&24&60&18
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\2^{1/2}\\3^{1/3}\\2^{1/2}3^{1/3}\\3^{2/3}\\2^{1/2}3^{2/3}
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
We can use the method from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/813566) to get a vector perpendicular to all the columns in the matrix above:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\-36\\12\\-6\\-6\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}^{\large T}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&0&0&0\\
2&0&0&2&1&0\\
3&2&6&0&0&3\\
4&12&3&8&12&0\\
60&4&20&15&3&20\\
17&120&90&24&60&18
\end{bmatrix}=0\tag{2}
$$
$(1)$ and $(2)$ imply that
$$
\alpha^6-6\alpha^4-6\alpha^3+12\alpha^2-36\alpha+1=0\tag{3}
$$
$(3)$ says that $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer. [A rational algebraic integer must be an integer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/309071) However, $1\lt\sqrt2\lt\frac32$ and $1\lt\sqrt[\large3]3\lt\frac32$, thus $2\lt\alpha\lt3$. Therefore, $\alpha$ must be irrational.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?